# Is $\arctan ( \tan ( π + (π/4) ) )$ equal to $π/4$ or undefined?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

We know than $\arctan ( \tan ( π + (π/4) ) )$ equals $x$ when $x$ belongs to the domain of $\tan x$ (and hence range of $\arctan x$).

Where $\arctan x$ and $\tan x$ are inverses of each other, and hence the domain of $\tan x$ equals the range of arctanx and the range of $\tan x$ equals the domain of $\arctan x$  (by the definition of inverse function).

Consider the expression: $\arctan ( \tan ( π + (π/4) ) )$.

$π+π/4$ does not belong to the range of $\arctan x$ and hence does not belong to the domain of $\tan x$ (which is the inverse of $\arctan x$).

And hence this expression is undefined as, if $F$ is a function then $F$ (number not in domain) is undefined.

Is this right?

Comment: The domain of $\arctan(\tan(x))$ IS $\mathbb R-\{n\pi+\pi/2\}$.

Comment: Okay. My bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined, $\arctan(\tan(\pi+\pi/4))=\arctan(\tan(5\pi/4))=\arctan1=\pi/4$.

Let's take a look at what is wrong with your reasoning:

> *$\pi+\pi/4$  does not belong to the range of $\arctan$ and hence does not belong to the domain of $\tan$ (which is the inverse of $\arctan$).*

This is incorrect in two ways:

1. The inverse of $\arctan x$ is not $\tan x$, instead, it is **the part of $\tan x$ with $x$ restrited to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$**.
2. *$x$  does not belong to the range of $\arctan$* merely means that $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$ does not hold; it does not mean $\arctan(\tan (x))$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have edited my question to address this. Please read the edit.

Comment: Since the part of tanx has a domain of -π/2 to π/2 then how can we evaluate tan(π+π/4)? π+π/4 isn't in the domain of this part of tanx

Comment: @MichaelFaraday I am not sure I understand your question. Maybe your confusion is in understanding the domain of $\tan$. By convention, when we say $\tan x$, we mean a function defined on $\mathbb R$ except for $\pi/2+n\pi (n\in\mathbb Z)$. If you plot this, you see that it consists of disjoint branches and is not globally invertible. When we say $\arctan x$ is the inverse of $\tan x$, we mean the inverse of **one of its branches**. Theoretically we can take any branch, but by convention, we take the branch of $\tan x$ with $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\tan\frac{5\pi}{4}=1$, $\arctan\tan\frac{5\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Although $\pi + \frac{\pi}{4} \notin$ Range of $\arctan x$, $\tan x$ is periodic with period $\pi$.

Your expression can be written as$$\arctan\left(\tan(\pi + \frac{\pi}{4})\right) = \arctan\left(\tan \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$